# Detect texts from image with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I tried to detect texts from image with their positions but always I don't get any result, than I use the script mention in this thread but still it need improvement or is there another method to detect texts in any orientation.

[Detect white rectangle on black & white image and crop (OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60794387/detect-white-rectangle-on-black-white-image-and-crop-opencv)

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'
#Read input image
img = cv2.imread('image attached')

#convert from BGR to HSV color space
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
#apply threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 8, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
#thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)
# find contours and get one with area about 180*35
# draw all contours in green and accepted ones in red
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
#area_thresh = 0
#min_area = 0.95*180*35
#max_area = 1.05*180*35
result = img.copy()
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
    #if area > min_area and area < max_area:
            #cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh)
print(text)
# show images
#cv2.imshow("GRAY", gray)
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Image :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need a lot more preprocessing to achieve optimal results. Before that, I would suggest adjusting the threshold because currently, most of the image gets washed out. Try the standard instead:

```
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

I would first rotate the image 90 degrees, detect the bounding boxes around the rectangles and then run tesseract on each of the rectangles.

Comment: Thank you
I find this which is work perfect, but slow with cpu: EasyOCR